# XSL-FO : Block element wrong height

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

Im trying to surround and image with 2 vertical gray bar using XSL-FO. I created a vertical separator with 180*1 dimension, and i'm able to render it correctly in my XSL.

Problem is, the `<fo:block>` element is taking too much height, and i cant seem to find a workaround, see image below ( the red is the background of the `<fo:block>` element, while the thin grey line is my separator. I've had good result by wrapping the whole `<fo-block>` into a `<fo:block-container>` but the separator isnt centered, and i wasnt able to center it.

This is my code

```
<fo:block height='1px' background-color='#DE122D'>
   <fo:external-graphic height='1px' content-width="scale-down-to-fit" src="url('images/verticalSeparator.png')" />
 </fo:block>
```

I put a background color in order to be able to see how much height it was taking.

Ultimately i'm trying to achieve the 2nd screenshot, there might be other way to do this ( perhaps something with border ? ) and i'm willing to try them. Simply notice that the 2 vertical bars are longer than the image, and that the content must be centered !

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should add some FO to your question so we can assist

Comment: i added the pertinent code afterwars, you might need to refresh :)

Comment: OK, set font-size to 0px and line-height to 0 on the block and test again

Comment: how about border-left and border-right? You can use a solid border instead of a bitmap

Comment: By the way, I think you should edit your question text ... you say "vertical" grey lines and I think you mean "horizontal" ... the grey lines in your good sample are horizontal lines.

Answer (score 0):

I might not understand your question, but based on the code posted you imply the rule is the issue and make too much space. If the rule is your issue, possibly you want to use an alternative structure than an image. For this you could use a leader and set the length to what you want and have no issues centering it. The following code:

```
    <fo:block text-align="center">Text Before</fo:block>
    <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="1px" line-height="0"><fo:leader color="silver" leader-length="2in" leader-pattern="rule"/></fo:block>
    <fo:block text-align="center">Text Between</fo:block>
    <fo:block text-align="center" font-size="1px" line-height="0"><fo:leader color="silver" leader-length="2in" leader-pattern="rule"/></fo:block>
    <fo:block text-align="center">Text After</fo:block>
```

Produces this output -- you can see no issues in spacing:

[image]